# How to count rows on PostgreSQL database in Django?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

How to count rows on PostgreSQL database in Django and show using highchart?

Example: I want to show how much record/row from 7.00am to 7.00 am next day.

models:

```
from django.db import models
   from datetime import datetime, date

class hujan(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    tanggal = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    dtinms = models.IntegerField()
    hujan = models.FloatField()
```

serializers:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import hujan, cahayasuhukelembapan

class hujanSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = hujan
        fields = ('tanggal','dtinms','hujan')
```

views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.renderers import TemplateHTMLRenderer
from .models import hujan
from .serializers import hujanSerializer

def homePageView(request):
  return render(request,'homepage.html')

class hujanlistall(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        Hujan = hujan.objects.all()
        serializer = hujanSerializer(Hujan, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data,safe=False)
```

Comment: You've used `highcharts` tag yet, unfortunately, this issue is not strictly related to it. Take a look at this blog post perhaps it will help you: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/post/create-a-dashboard-using-highcharts-and-django/

Comment: actually, it was quite related. because at the end i'm using highchart for visualization.

Comment: Yes, yet you have an issue of how to prepare data for `highcharts`. I'm not a Django expert so I'm not able to help you. This is the data structure for `highcharts` line series: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data.

Answer (score 0):

Modify "views.py" file,

```
import datetime
class hujanlistall(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        Hujan = hujan.objects.filter(tanggal__range = (datetime.datetime.combine(start_date,datetime.time.min),datetime.datetime.combine(end_date, datetime.time.max)))
        RowCount = len(Hujan)
        serializer = hujanSerializer(Hujan, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data,safe=False)
```